# find the frequency with Fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a problem for obtain the frequency of oscillations with Fourier,

For example if  I have

```
tf = 60;
NN = (tf + 1)/0.001;
dt = tf/NN;
data = Table[Sin[t], {t, 0., tf, 0.001}];
fft = Fourier[data];
peak1 = First[Position[Abs[fft], Max[Abs[fft]]]];
```

The frequency is obtained would be $2\pi k/ N dt$, where k is the position of the first peak. If I evaluate this expression I do not obtain the frequency.

Comment: There's a factor of `2 Pi` in formula for [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html).  Shouldn't the frequency be `(peak1 -1)/tf`?

Comment: Why did you set up NN and dt if you never use them on line 4? Also your Sin[t] should be `Sin[2 pi f]` for frequency f. You also need to take a look at the FourierParameters option of Fourier and finally, you should account for your sampling rate too.

Comment: See the "Applications" section of the docs of `Fourier` for an example of how to determine the frequency.  The shortcoming of that example is that it uses a `dt` (or `dx`) of `1`, and doesn't show how to modify the various steps. However, it's not hard to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

OP's apparent intention:

```
tf = 60;
NN = (tf)/0.001;
dt = tf/NN;
data = Table[Sin[t], {t, 0., tf, 0.001}];
fft = Fourier[data];
peak1 = First@First[Position[Abs[fft], Max[Abs[fft]]]]
freq = (peak1 - 1)/tf
```

> ```
> (*
>   11
>   0.166667
> *)
> ```

It's closest estimate possible, since the adjacent estimates have a larger error:

```
1/(2 Pi) - (peak1 - {0, 1, 2})/tf // N
```

> ```
> (*  {-0.0241784, -0.00751172, 0.00915494}  *)
> ```

Here is the method from the docs for [`Fourier`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html) (under "Applications"), which uses a more sophisticated approach:

```
Min[TakeLargest[Abs@fft, 2]];
peaks = Position[Abs[fft], x_ /; x >= %];
pos = First@First[peaks]
```

> ```
> (*  11  *)
> ```

```
n = Length@fft;
fr = Abs[Fourier[data*Exp[2 Pi I (pos - 2) N[Range[0, n - 1]]/n], 
    FourierParameters -> {0, 2/n}]];
frpos = Position[fr, Max[fr]][[1, 1]];

period = N[n/(pos - 2 + 2 (frpos - 1)/n)] dt
```

> ```
> (*  6.29278  *)
> ```

```
frequency = 1/period
1./(2 Pi)
```

> ```
> (*
>   0.158912
>   0.159155
> *)
> ```